# Why doesn't filter() work narrowing the Locator

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright, playwright-typescript

I can't publish the code, but I wrote this HTML file that replicates the scenario (https://coral-nanci-88.tiiny.site/):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        }
    
        .main {
            display: flex;
        }
    
        .sidebar {
            width: 20vw;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            height: 100vh;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }
    
        .content {
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 4rem;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="side-item_lev1">
                        <div class="lev1-header">Lev1 item - 1</div>
                        <div class="lev1-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="side-item_lev2">
                                    <div class="lev1-header">Lev2 item</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="side-item_lev1">
                        <div class="lev1-header">Lev1 item - 2</div>
                        <div class="lev1-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="side-item_lev2">
                                    <div class="lev1-header">Lev2 item</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p class="content-desc">CONTENT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

If you run this test (I used vscode with Live Server extension):

```
test('test-sidebar', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html")
    const site = new Site(page)
    await site.sidebar.clickLevOneItem("Lev1 item - 1")
})
```

using those Classes:

```
class Site {
    private readonly page: Page
    public readonly sidebar: SideBar

    constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page
        this.sidebar = new SideBar(this.page.locator(".sidebar"))
    }
}

class SideBar {
    public readonly baseNode: Locator

    constructor(baseNode: Locator) {
        this.baseNode = baseNode;
    }

    public async clickLevOneItem(name: string) {
        await this.baseNode.locator(".side-item_lev1")
            .filter({ has: this.baseNode.locator(".lev1-header", { hasText: name }) })
            .click()
    }
}
```

it's like the filter() method does not work..
But, if you pass the entire page to SideBar:

```
class Site {
    private readonly page: Page
    public readonly sidebar: SideBar

    constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page
        this.sidebar = new SideBar(page)
    }
}

class SideBar {
    public readonly baseNode: Page

    /**
     * Create the common page object
     * @param {Locator} baseNode - 
     */
    constructor(baseNode: Page) {
        this.baseNode = baseNode;
    }

     ...
}
```

The filter works, find the DOM object and then click it.
But why if I narrow the class using Locator, without passing the entire page, it stops working. I don't get it.

Comment: Can you convert your code into a snippet that runs so we can play around with it?

Comment: Did it, but how can this help you to execute the test?

Comment: @LajosArpad We can't execute Node in Stack Snippets.

Comment: I inserted a temporary (https://coral-nanci-88.tiiny.site/) link on which you can open the scenario i created

Comment: Thanks, but just running the stack snippet is sufficient. No need for an external site, especially if it's temporary (since the goal is that the question will be accessible to future visitors with the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

POMs are great once you have working code, but the extra layers of abstraction obfuscate the fundamental problem a bit here. I think it's easier to see what's going on if you remove the POM and isolate the single locator action, then re-add the POM once it's working:

```js
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="side-item_lev1">
      <div class="lev1-header">Lev1 item - 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="side-item_lev1">
      <div class="lev1-header">Lev1 item - 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body></html>`;

test("sidebar", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const baseNode = page.locator(".sidebar");
  await baseNode
    .locator(".side-item_lev1")
    .filter({
      has: baseNode.locator(".lev1-header", {
        hasText: "Lev1 item - 1"
      })
    })
    .click();
});
```

The problem boils down to whether you can use `baseNode` in a nested manner, as done above.

Although this looks like it should work, apparently, this isn't possible, since it's not shown in [the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filter-by-childdescendant) anywhere, which say:

> The filtering locator must be relative to the original locator and is queried starting with the original locator match, not the document root.

...then proceed to show only examples using `page.` inside of `has:`.

One option is to use `page` in the nested locator:

```js
// ...
    .filter({
      has: page.locator(".lev1-header", {
        // ^^^^
        hasText: "Lev1 item - 1"
      })
    })
// ...
```

Or skip `.filter()` entirely and use pure locators. This is easier to understand and avoids having to pass `page` into your nested POM.

```js
await page
  .locator(".sidebar")
  .locator(".side-item_lev1")
  .locator(".lev1-header")
  .getByText("Lev1 item - 1", {exact: true})
  .click();
```

or take advantage of natural CSS chaining when possible:

```js
await page
  .locator(".sidebar .side-item_lev1 .lev1-header")
  .getByText("Lev1 item - 1", {exact: true})
  .click();
```

or:

```js
await page
  .locator(".sidebar .side-item_lev1 .lev1-header")
  .locator("text='Lev1 item - 1'") // exact match
  .click();
```

or, most precisely:

```js
await page
  .locator(".sidebar .side-item_lev1 .lev1-header:text-is('Lev1 item - 1')")
  .click();
```

In general, CSS classes aren't considered good practice in tests, so you might consider using [test ids](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-test-id) or [user-visible behavior](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior), if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Anyway, my original locator is (".side-item_lev1") which is a parent of (".lev1-header").. so i still don't understand why filter doesn't work in my case..

Comment: Yes, it intuitively _looks_ like it should work, which is why this is a good question. But I don't see that querying by nested selectors is mentioned anywhere (I won't say it's definitely not possible--it may be, and I'm missing something). Playwright seems to automatically query within the subtree even if you use `page.` in the filtered locator. As mentioned in the post, I try to avoid `.filter()` when possible, since the syntax and behavior is rather jarring to me. I like having a single chain rather than objects with other chained properties branching off.